# why can't i pip install Pyrebase in python?

Tags: python, pip, pyrebase

So I am trying to `pip install Pyrebase` in pycharm
but i am getting this error

```
   command: 'c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\myworkprojects\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\
Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tcpoer0q\\pycryptodome\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tcpoer0q\\pycryptodome\\setup.py'"'"';
f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdis
t_wheel -d 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-2tffvi57'
       cwd: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tcpoer0q\pycryptodome\
  Complete output (364 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto
  copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
  
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycryptodome
  Running setup.py clean for pycryptodome
Failed to build pycryptodome
Installing collected packages: pycryptodome, Pyrebase
    Running setup.py install for pycryptodome ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\myworkprojects\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData
\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tcpoer0q\\pycryptodome\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tcpoer0q\\pycryptodome\\setup.py'"'"
';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' in
stall --record 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dxesdn53\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\hp\p
ycharmprojects\myworkprojects\venv\include\site\python3.8\pycryptodome'
         cwd: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tcpoer0q\pycryptodome\
    Complete output (363 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
   
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\myworkprojects\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv
[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tcpoer0q\\pycryptodome\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tcp
oer0q\\pycryptodome\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(cod
e, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dxesdn53\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
 --install-headers 'c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\myworkprojects\venv\include\site\python3.8\pycryptodome' Check the logs for full command output.

(venv) C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\MyWorkProjects>pip install Pyrebase
Collecting Pyrebase
  Using cached Pyrebase-3.0.27-py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-toolbelt==0.7.0 in c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\myworkprojects\venv\lib\site-packages (from Pyrebase) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: gcloud==0.17.0 in c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\myworkprojects\venv\lib\site-packages (from Pyrebase) (0.17.0)
Collecting pycryptodome==3.4.3
  Using cached pycryptodome-3.4.3.tar.gz (6.5 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests==2.11.1 in c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\myworkprojects\venv\lib\site-packages (from Pyrebase) (2.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: oauth2client==3.0.0 in c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\myworkprojects\venv\lib\site-packages (from Pyrebase) (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-jwt==2.0.1 in c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\myworkprojects\venv\lib\site-packages (from Pyrebase) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: httplib2>=0.9.1 in c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\myworkprojects\venv\lib\site-packages (from gcloud==0.17.0->Pyrebase) (0.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: googleapis-common-protos in c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\myworkprojects\venv\lib\site-packages (from gcloud==0.17.0->Pyrebase) (1.52.0)

Requirement already satisfied: protobuf!=3.0.0.b2.post1,>=3.0.0b2 in c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\myworkprojects\venv\lib\site-packages (from gcloud==0.17.0->Pyrebase
) (3.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\myworkprojects\venv\lib\site-packages (from gcloud==0.17.0->Pyrebase) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.7 in c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\myworkprojects\venv\lib\site-packages (from oauth2client==3.0.0->Pyrebase) (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.0.5 in c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\myworkprojects\venv\lib\site-packages (from oauth2client==3.0.0->Pyrebase) (0.2.8
)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa>=3.1.4 in c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\myworkprojects\venv\lib\site-packages (from oauth2client==3.0.0->Pyrebase) (4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: jws>=0.1.3 in c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\myworkprojects\venv\lib\site-packages (from python-jwt==2.0.1->Pyrebase) (0.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\myworkprojects\venv\lib\site-packages (from protobuf!=3.0.0.b2.post1,>=3.0.0b2->gcloud==0.17
.0->Pyrebase) (50.3.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: pycryptodome
  Building wheel for pycryptodome (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\myworkprojects\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\
Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h4tye5vg\\pycryptodome\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h4tye5vg\\pycryptodome\\setup.py'"'"';
f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdis
t_wheel -d 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-n2zgp_ai'
       cwd: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h4tye5vg\pycryptodome\
  Complete output (364 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto
  copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
  
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\myworkprojects\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv
[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h4tye5vg\\pycryptodome\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h4t
ye5vg\\pycryptodome\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(cod
e, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_4my5q46\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
 --install-headers 'c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\myworkprojects\venv\include\site\python3.8\pycryptodome' Check the logs for full command output.
```

this is not the full error
it exceeds the limit
i dont know how to fix this

Comment: Can you [gist](https://gist.github.com) the full error and link it from here?

Comment: like this? [my gist](https://gist.github.com/yAmIZErO31/00d1fc554a1b5b4d9978cb0966d147a8)

Answer (score 0):

please switch `pyrebase4`, this is forked from pyrebase and is well maintained

```
pip install pyrebase4
```